# Seleccionar Items de un Select Multiple en laravel JS

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Vista

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">productos para la orden:*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
       {{ Form::select('products[]', $products, null, ['id' => 'products', 'multiple' => 'multiple', "class"=>"form-control multi-select"]) }}
       <span class="errors">{{ $errors->first('shipping_method_id') }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ese es mi SELECT multiple donde llamo desde mi controlador a todos mis productos cuyo stock sea mayor que 0

Controlador

```
$products = Product::where('stock','>','0')->lists('name', 'id');

return View::make("backend.orders.create")
       ->with("action","create")
       ->with('products',$products);
```

¿Cómo selecciono esos ítemes para que me los imprima más abajo y luego poder ir seleccionando la cantidad de este ítem? Supongamos que tienes un ítem café, lo seleccionas y abajo carga este ítem y te coloca un contador para que le digas la cantidad de cafés que quieres y luego en el controlador se resten del stock.

Comment: La cantidad seleccionada se resta una vez presionado algún boton de 'Agregar al carrito de compras' o similar? o se haría por ajax al escribir o seleccionar la cantidad?

Answer (score 1):

para seleccionar los elementos en un select multiple puedes utilizar la función click de jquery, cuando haces alguna selección en el select, la función .click te devuelve un array con las opciones seleccionadas previamente, lo que hice fue asignarle un valor identificador en el value para poder hacer los cambios que se desean, te dejo el código para que te des una idea.

```js
$('#products').click(function (e) {
  //se consigue todos los valores seleccionados en el select multiple
  //en este caso el valor que se consigue en el atributo value
  //es un identificador del producto
  this.seleccion  = $(this).val();

  //se limpia el div para imprimir
  $('#imprimir').html('');

  //se valida que this.seleccion sea mayor a 0
  if ( this.seleccion.length > 0 ) {
    //se recorren todos los valores seleccionados en el select products
    for (var i = this.seleccion.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      this.cantidad = $("#products [value='" + this.seleccion[i] + "']").attr('data-cantidad');
      this.texto    = $("#products [value='" + this.seleccion[i] + "']").text();
      this.cambio   = $("#products [value='" + this.seleccion[i] + "']").attr('data-cambio');

      //se crea el html con un input para poner la cantidad a descontar
      this.html = '<div>' + this.texto + '- Stock: <span id="cambio' + this.seleccion[i] + '">' + this.cantidad 
      + '</span> - <input type="text" id="cantidad' + this.seleccion[i] 
      + '" data-i="' + this.seleccion[i] 
      + '" class="accion" value="' + this.cambio + '" /> Quedarian <span id="nueva_cantidad' 
      + this.seleccion[i] + '">' + this.cantidad + '</span></div>';

      $('#imprimir').append( this.html );
    }
    //una vez creado los input con la clase .accion
    //se ejecuta un trigger para hacer las operaciones del stock
    $('.accion').trigger('keyup');
  };
});

$('#imprimir').on('keyup', '.accion', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //identificador del input
  this.i = $(this).attr('data-i');

  this.numero_uno = parseInt( $(this).val() );
  this.numero_dos = parseInt( $('#cambio' + this.i ).text() );

  //cada vez que hacemos un cambio a #products
  //el valor del input .accion se pierde ya que lo dibuja desde 0
  //para evitar esto, en esta linea se lo asigno a un atributo para guardarlo
  $("#products [value='" + this.i + "']").attr('data-cambio', $(this).val() );

  //resta del stock con la cantidad del input .accion
  this.nueva_cantidad = this.numero_dos - this.numero_uno;

  //cambiando la cantidad en stock
  $('#nueva_cantidad' + this.i ).text( this.nueva_cantidad );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">productos para la orden:*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <select name="productos" multiple id="products" class="form-control multi-select">
            <option value="1" data-cantidad="8" data-cambio="0">cafe</option>
            <option value="2" data-cantidad="3" data-cambio="0">jugo</option>
            <option value="3" data-cantidad="4" data-cambio="0">dulce</option>
            <option value="4" data-cantidad="6" data-cambio="0">refresco</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>Selecionaste:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="imprimir" class="col-md-12">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-info" >Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cada vez que seleccionas un elemento del select, te dibuja en el div #imprimir el stock del producto, un input .accion para asignar el valor a restar y por ultimo la resta del stock menos el valor a restar.

Espero que te ayude.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]